# How to download the file from sftp or ftp server via android download manager?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying  to download a file using the Android Download Manager. So far, I've not succeeded.

It keeps failing on the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP URIs/HTTPS
```

I've also tried to convert path to url using the following code:

```
String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s";
ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, filePath);
```

But I got the same error.

Please can you help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Use some Java API for FTP. You are using HTTP API to download from FTP server. A quick Google search landed me on this https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes,now I used Java API.But I can't able to download file via Android download manager.how to download the file via ADM(Android download manager)?

Comment: In that case you might need to spend some time on Android API documentation. If I get any clue I will post it. Maybe some intent delegates to ADM.

Comment: Thanks for the replay...I will check